# Plot as a "ball" in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, random, sequential

I don't know if the title is clear enought.
I have some plot in Python:

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/8/3/3aeec9bae5dcfadf4e3109a87f27a723-full.gif

What I need to do is transfer cutted parts of circles to the other side of plot. For example - the pink one on the left side is cutted so I need to show the rest of it on the right side. So I want to make something like unfolded sphere.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You could plot everything three times, once with its regular x value, once with x-1 and once with x+1, but keep the x axis limits at 0 to 1.

Or with a little more work, you could just double plot the ones that are near the edge, once with the regular x value and once with x +/- 1.